# RuntimeException: Application "" could not be found in the registry.

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

### Background

*Goal: I am attempting to install the Simics Tools for Eclipse plugin on Windows 7 64-bit.*

I am using Eclipse Indigo for Java (64-bit <-- This will be a problem later) and have just installed the C/C++ IDE plugin, GEF draw2d plugin, and the Simics Tools for Eclipse. Once the installation of these plugins successfully finished, I restarted Eclipse and proceeded to launch Simics Control from inside Eclipse. An error dialog stated that this plugin could not run on 64 bit Eclipse.

To solve this problem, I decided to install a 32-bit version of Eclipse next to my current setup and to uninstall the plugins I had just installed (C/C++, GEF, and Simics) from Eclipse. First, I was going to remove the plugins to avoid wasting space. I went to **Help->About->Installation Details** and selected the installed plugins to uninstall. Removing the plugins appeared to be successful until I restarted Eclipse.

### Issue

After the removal of the plugins, when Eclipse launches, the splash screen appears without a progress bar along the bottom to show what is currently being loaded. After a few seconds, the splash screen disappears and an error dialog shows up: *An error has occurred. See the log file C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\configuration\1322503657546.log*

Contents of 1322503657546.log:

```
!SESSION 2011-11-28 12:07:37.255 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-11-28 12:07:39.521
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWTCodeFormatterApplication, com.virtutech.simics.ui.app, com.virtutech.simics.ui.appAn, com.virtutech.simics.ui.simpleSimicsApplication, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.ant.ui.antRunner, org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM, org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.console.profile.StorageFileEditor, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator, org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore.Ecore2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.java.Java2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose.Rose2GenModel, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench, org.eclipse.uml2.uml.ecore.importer.UML2GenModel, org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate, org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer, org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.preview.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

The important line appears to be `java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "" could not be found in the registry.` After searching the web, it appears that this is a generic error.

Resources:

- [Eclipse Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/684320/)
- I tried [removing my
  /eclipse/configuration/ folder](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-tools/865/Eclipse-application-id-problem) and relaunching, but that created a whole bunch of
  new errors.

### Ideas

1. Removing /eclipse/configuration folder and relaunching. Failed.
2. Edit config.ini. **Should I be concerned that `eclipse.product` and `eclipse.application` are blank?**

   Contents of config.ini:

   ```
   #This configuration file was written by:
   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
   #Mon Nov 28 11:18:26 CST 2011
   org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
   eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
   osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
   osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.0.v20110613.jar
   equinox.use.ds=true
   eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
   osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110502-1955.jar@1\:start
   org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
   eclipse.product=
   osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
   osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201105210645.jar
   osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
   eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
   eclipse.application=
   ```
3. Edit eclipse.ini.

   Contents of eclipse.ini:

   ```
   -startup
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
   --launcher.library
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
   -showsplash
   org.eclipse.platform
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256m
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   -product
   org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256M
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
   -Xms512m
   -Xmx1024m
   ```

How can I successfully launch Eclipse again? I would really rather not have to perform a clean install since it took a long time to get it set up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to load an existing workspace?  It's possible that the workspace contains settings that expect the uninstalled plugins to be there.  Try loading a brand-new workspace.

Comment: Problem is, I can't launch Eclipse at this point to load a workspace. Paul's answer below fixed it for me. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Empty

```
eclipse.application=
```

in config.ini is problem.
Default value you can use is

```
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

Same counts for empty eclipse.product

```
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first eclipse included C/C++ as part of its zip, as it was Eclipse for C/C++ developers. That's what the product `org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product` says.  You didn't install the C/C++ runtime separately, although you might have installed the source plugins separately.  But however you told it to remove configurations wiped out that product, and now that install is broken.  You're best bet is to remove it and unzip your ZIP again.

Other options:  You can roll back your configuration change, using the p2 director on the command line.  Something like:

```
eclipse/eclipse -noSplash \
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-repository file:$(pwd)/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/SDKProfile.profile \
-profile SDKProfile \
-revert 1299499722731
```

See http://pweclipse.blogspot.com/2011/03/working-state-from-p2-update.html for a description of the process (it's a hit or miss proposition, but maybe better than deleting and unzipping).

Answer (score 3):

Control Panel-> Advanced System Setting -> Environment Variables ->

Now you have to do 2 things:

1-Create a new variable 
 variable name=**JAVA_HOME**
variable value=**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01**

2-Edite the Path variable and add this at the end of that
**;%JAVA_HOME%\bin**

Answer (score 2):

I tried clearing the configuration in configuration tab and it worked !!

check the "clear configuration area before launch" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configuration folder previous to update then replace the current with the non updated one. This will solve the problem.