# Eclipse can't launch after update

Tags: android, eclipse

I use eclipse Juno to work with android. After I updated an android plugin, I can't launch eclipse anymore. It give me this error in log file :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.console.profile.StorageFileEditor, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.preview, org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.application, org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator, org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore.Ecore2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.java.Java2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose.Rose2GenModel, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

How can I get my eclipse back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first eclipse included C/C++ as part of its zip, as it was Eclipse for C/C++ developers. That's what the product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product says. You didn't install the C/C++ runtime separately, although you might have installed the source plugins separately. But however you told it to remove configurations wiped out that product, and now that install is broken. You're best bet is to remove it and unzip your ZIP again.

Go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300648/runtimeexception-application-could-not-be-found-in-the-registry).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I already re-download and it works fine.

Comment: I told you this After 10 minutes when you asked that question. You can accept answer if that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the help tab - check for updates and update the android sdk packages. This had happened to me as well and all that i had to do was to update the sdk packages. This might happen if you try and install new devices thru the SDK manager. You would have to update the SDKs of the existing API's as well.