# How to execute a java eclipse plugin jar from command line using equinox launcher?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have been trying to launch my plugin project from windows command line, but I get the following error every time. I have exported my project into a runnable jar and placed this jar in the plugins directory of eclipse. Kindly help me with this.

```
!SESSION 2015-11-17 03:42:07.220 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application helloworld.runtimeApp
Command-line arguments:  -consoleLog -console -application helloworld.runtimeApp

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-11-17 03:42:08.578
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "helloworld.runtimeApp" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: 

    org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.ant.ui.antRunner, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator, org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore.Ecore2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.java.Java2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose.Rose2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner.
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: I am using this command for executing my plugin                                                    :java -jar plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.0.v20070523.jar -consoleLog -console -nosplash -application xyz.jar

Comment: May be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12678359/2691625 ?

Comment: You can't just run a plugin from the command line, you must write a complete Eclipse RCP application.

Comment: I get the same error for RCP application